# Condition && in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a first code that looks like this, it's a console list with on / off buttons:

```
const ConsoleDisplay = () => {
  const statusData = useContext(StatusDataContext);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [oneConsoleDataIndex, setOneConsoleDataIndex] = useState();

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {statusData.map((data, index) => {
        const handleOpen = () => {
          setOpen(true);
          setOneConsoleDataIndex(index);
        };

        const displayBtnStatusOncycle =
          !timesUp &&
            (data['cycle in progress 1'] || //boleen
              data['cycle in progress 2'])
            ? 'var(--btn-green)'
            : 'var(--btn-grey)';

        const displayBtnStatusOffcycle = timesUp
          ? 'var(--btn-red)'
          : 'var(--btn-grey)';
```

When I click on one of the consoles, it opens a modal that I can close. At the top right, I can switch consoles without closing the window by clicking on another console. In this modal, I have the same information in a new component:

```
const ConsoleDetails = ({ setIndex, index, open, close }) => {
    const statusData = useContext(StatusDataContext);
    const data = statusData[index];
    
    return (  
      <Card
        onClick={() => setIndex(i)}
      >
       <span>
       {data && data.console_nickname
        ? data.console_nickname
        : data && data.console_id}
       </span>
      </Card>
      const displayBtnStatusOncycle =
        !timesUp &&
        data &&
        (data['cycle in progress 1'] || //boleen
          data['cycle in progress 2'])
          ? 'var(--btn-green)'
          : 'var(--btn-grey)';
    
      const displayBtnStatusOffcycle = timesUp
        ? 'var(--btn-red)'
        : 'var(--btn-grey)';
```

There is something I don't understand, why use **data && (data['cycle in progress 1']** in the second component instead of (data['cycle in progress 1']? or just {data.console_nickname ? data.console_nickname : data.console_id} ? Why use **data &&**?

Comment: So that you wont get an error when data is null or undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume for a moment that `statusData[index]` does not exist, and `data` is therefore `undefined`.
If you would then use the snippet you are proposing:

```
data.console_nickname
```

That would evaluate to

```
undefined.console_nickname
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'console_nickname' of undefined
```

If you would however prepend it with `data &&`, the statement would evaluate to

```
undefined && undefined.console_nickname
```

Written like this, the first half of the operation evaluates to false (`undefined` is falsy) and prevents the second half of the statement to be run. This is only necessary when you want to access a property on an object that might be undefined.

### Optional chaining (ES2020)

A recent addition to the JavaScript language is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It allows you to access a property of an object that might be undefined:

```
data?.console_nickname
```

If `data` is now `undefined`, the entire statement will evaluate to `undefined` without throwing an error. Depending on your use case, this can replace the `data &&` trick mentioned before.

If needed, you can even chain these lookups like this:

```
data?.propOne?.propTwo?.propThree
```

If any of these props down the line is `undefined`, the entire chain evaluates to `undefined`. This makes it very safe and easy to traverse deep inside your data.

**Beware** that this is a recent addition to the language, and although all major browsers do already support it you should check it with your project. Since you're using React, your code will probably already be preprocessed anyway and language features like this usually get translated to versions that are compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I understand much better, however, this operator could have been applied also in the first component?

Comment: If you're talking about the optional chaining: you can also use it like `data?.['cycle in progress 1']` when you need to use square brackets. I just wanna note that there is nothing wrong with using `data &&`, as described in the docs @CodeoftheWarrior linked to in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

The above comment by Daemes is correct, but it's good to go to documentation and realize the react team recommends this form of conditional rendering.